# Matrix/Playa approach to i18n

Tags: matrix, playa, multi-language, multilingual

My current solution for making my site multilingual is using this [very simple plugin](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/language-variables)
which is very close to how Codeigniter does it.

However, it seems this cannot be used for things like Matrix/Playa since the strings are not in the template files.

What is the best approach for making Matrix/Playa multilingual?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [Publisher](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/publisher) add-on, it supports both Playa and Matrix.

More information can be found on the [boldminded.com](http://boldminded.com/add-ons/publisher/third-party-add-ons) website.

Comment: Is there no way to implement it without using addons?